# iOS core data object model change in production application

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite, core-data

I have an app that is in production use at the moment.  I have made major changes to the next version of this app's Core Data model.

To avoid a ton of conversion work from the old data model to the new one, I have simply renamed the new object model and database, thus causing the new version of the app to no longer reference the old database (this is not an issue, as the old database data is tiny, and not needed).

There is one piece of data that I do need from the old database however, and I would hate to have users need to re-enter it manually into the new database.

My Question:
What are my options to get this piece of data into the new database?

Can I run a query against the sqlite database and simply enter into the new database?  Or do I need to create a whole other persistent store & object model to pull the data?

Or am I missing something all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for both suggestions above.  I ended up using the following to solve my issue:

Steps:

- Attempt to connect to old SQLite database.
- If connection was successful, read the record.
- Create a new managed object in the managed object context.
- Populate values in managed object with those from sql results.
- Persist managed object.
- Delete old database.

```
NSString *dbFilePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectoryString] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"RPS.sqlite"];

sqlite3 *database;

if (sqlite3_open([dbFilePath UTF8String], &database)) {
    NSLog(@"sqlite3_open: failed");
} else {
    NSString *nsquery = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM ztable"];
    const char *query = [nsquery UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    int prepareCode = (sqlite3_prepare_v2( database, query, -1, &statement, NULL));
    if(prepareCode == SQLITE_OK) {
        MyTable *myTableRecord;
        NSLog(@"About to start adding the data");
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSLog(@"***************** row returned ******************");

            myObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"myTable" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

            [myTable setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7)] forKey:@"field1"];
            [myTable setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 8)] forKey:@"field2"];

            [self saveContext];

        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        NSLog(@"Added sqlite3 data");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Prepare code was not right: %d",prepareCode);
    }

    NSError *err;
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    [filemgr removeItemAtPath:dbFilePath error:&err];
    NSLog(@"Deleted old sqlite3 database");
}
```

Comment: This is a nifty solution. I assume you did not attempt an in-place CoreData migration because your model changes were do severe? Certainly, for "simple" model changes, automatic migration is the way to go...

Comment: Exactly.. the automatic migration didn't cover all of the relationship changes, etc.. that I had made.  This may be a bit hacky.. but it's simple :).

Comment: Simple works. :-) There is a way to write a "real" migration that is not an automatic migration and keep all the hidden stuff (like the SQLite database) hidden. But that can be "real" work to get right. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you would just need to copy the data over to the new database on the user's first-run of the updated app. At that point you could probably clear out the old one so it's taking up space for nothing. Not sure what more of a sophisticated solution would be needed than that. Seems adequate.

Comment: I guess I am wondering on the best/simplest approach to do just that.  I would rather not have 2 object model's etc... just for this one time operation.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, I think you should use core data to connect to your old database and pull data out and then move it to your new database. After you're done, you should delete the old database file with something like this (NOTE I'm assuming you are storing core data results into SQLite):

```
- (NSURL *)urlForDocumentsDirectoryWithFile:(NSString *)fileName {
    NSURL *docPath = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    return [docPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
}

- (void)deleteFileFromDocumentsIfExists:(NSString *)fileName {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *filePath = [self urlForDocumentsDirectoryWithFile:fileName];
    NSLog(@"Deleting file: %@", filePath.absoluteString);
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[filePath path]])
    {
        BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtURL:filePath error:&error];
        if (!success) NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Deletion code:

```
[self deleteFileFromDocumentsIfExists:@"MyOldDatabaseName.sqlite"];
```

I wouldn't worry about having 2 object models if you're only ever using the old one once... ever. I can see where it's a waste to have "used once" code in your app, but even skipping Core Data and querying manually still requires you to have this.

Also, I have a DataAccessManager unit that I dump all of core data's ridiculous initialization code into so it makes it easy for me to access multiple contexts, if your concern is that you're writing that all by hand you may want to move it to a sharable unit.